# Remove the previous marker and add marker in the updated lat lng

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, xmlhttprequest

I have a gps device which sends data every 10 seconds. I am saving the data (lat, lng) in the MySql database., I am retrieving the data from the DB and putting the markers on those lat lng using xmlHttpRequest(). I am also using setInterval() to xmlHttpRequest on 10 seconds. The markers are being added finely but new markers are added after refresh the whol site, not after 10 seconds on xmlhttpreq.

Also I have two problems -

1. My xmlHttpRequest() is refreshing fine after 10 seconds and getting the get_data.php file as i am seeing from Network,XHR but it is not adding new marker on the map, but the xmlHttp is requested after 10 seconds. How can i also update the marker?
2. Markers are being added according to the DB data but i do not want many markers, i just want one marker which will be updated position every 10 seconds. So the previous marker will be deleted and the new marker will be added. How can i do that? Below is my code -

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">




#map-canvas{
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <title> Google Map Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        //var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


function makeRequest(url, callback) {
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(request)
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        callback(request);
    }
}
    request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
console.log(request)
              }

        function initialise(){
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.7000, 90.3667),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);    

    makeRequest('get_data.php', function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        displayLocation(data[i]);
    }
         });
    // var myLatLng = {lat: 23.7000, lng: 90.3667};
    //  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //     map: map, 
    //     position: myLatLng,
    //     title: 'test!'
    // });

        }
        setInterval("makeRequest('get_data.php')",10000);

    function displayLocation(location) {

//var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'  + location.lat        +'</strong>'
  //              + '<br/>'     + location.lon + '</div>';

console.log(location.lat)
// location = JSON.parse(location)
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: position,
        title: 'test!'
    });



    // google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    //     infoWindow.setContent(content);
    //     infoWindow.open(map,marker);
    // });
}


        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
initialise();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

get_data.php

```
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "gpsdata") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $sql = "select * from locations";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    $emparray = [];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($emparray);

    mysqli_close($connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, both involve keeping a reference to the marker outside of the `displayLocation` function:

1. use the reference to move the existing marker

```
var marker;
function displayLocation(location) {
  console.log(location.lat)
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
    if (marker && marker.setPosition) {
      // if the marker already exists, move it (set its position)
      marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
      // create a new marker, keeping a reference
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: position,
        title: 'test!'
      });
    }
}
```

2. remove the existing marker from the map and create a new one

```
var marker;
function displayLocation(location) {
  console.log(location.lat)
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
    if (marker && marker.setMap) {
      // if the marker already exists, remove it from the map
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    // create a new marker, keeping a reference
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map, 
      position: position,
      title: 'test!'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng)))
        .title("test!"));
```

in displayLocation function

Comment: But i think that won't delete my previous markers, right? What i want to do is to have only one marker, the newest one.

Comment: Then you require a refresh of map.